# Run the ClaimCenter server in debug mode with the command line

Tags: guidewire, claimcenter

As you know, Guidewire Studio takes a lot of memory; at the level of testing, I just want to run the ClaimCenter server.

Do we run the server in debug mode with the command line without opening the GW studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command line to start the Guidewire application server in debug mode.

```
gwb runServer -Denv=envName
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gwb runServer -Denv=envName
gwb runServer -Denv=envName -x compile
```

The first command will still compile the ClaimCenter code.  If your ClaimCenter instance is not taking updates from a repository, the 2nd command will skip the compile step & launch the instance faster.

More info about this & other switches can be found in Guidewire’s documentation here:
https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1011/admin/topics/t_hp2141842.html (you’ll need to login with your customer or partner credentials to access this page).

Answer (score 0):

We can use the file `gwb.bat`. In fact, on `Windows CMD environment`, we run the following command line to start the Guidewire application server.

```
gwb runServer -Denv=local
```

Task List of `gwb.bat`
[image]